# Shell Script to Toggle VPN On and Off

Tags: shell-script, vpn

I am currently toggling my [Hotspot Shield](https://www.hotspotshield.com/) on Ubuntu 20.04.3 using the terminal; `hotspotshield connect US` to connect (to a US server) and `hotspotshield disconnect` to disconnect.

I would like to map this functionality to a single key in order to toggle the VPN on and off. I would like to use `hotspotshield status`, which returns,

```
Client is running    : no
VPN connection state : disconnected
```

if the client isn't running to evaluate whether to run the `connect` or `disconnect` commands. I planned on doing this by passing the output of `hotspotshield status` as a string and searching for "no" as that string does not appear in the output if the client isn't running. However I am having trouble interpreting the output.

Here is my script so far (note that I have never tried anything like this in bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

status=$(hotspotshield status)

if [[status =~ "no"]]; then
    hotspotshield connect US
else; then
    hotspotshield disconnect
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors, fixed looks like somewhat similar:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

status=$(hotspotshield status)

if [[ "$status" =~ no ]]; then
    hotspotshield connect US
else
    hotspotshield disconnect
fi
```

Please, use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) before posting here next time. Thank you.